# Datepicker not working inside jquery dialogbox

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker, datetimepicker, dialog

I have implemented datepicker inside jquery dialog box  and i when i click outside dialogbox the calender disappears and it does not appear back when i click inside my datepicker textbox. this is causing me problem as i want that calender appears back as soon as i click inside textbox. the following is my piece of code . any help within an hour will be appreciated much.

**Date picker:**

```
//applying datepicker for renew job popup.
//added by hkaur5

$(function(){
    //Applying datepicker-------------
    $("input#job_expiry_date").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        maxDate: '1M',
        minDate: '0',
        onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
            $("#date_to").datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
        }
        //showButtonPanel: true,
    });
});
```

**Dialog Box:**

```
//Alert box for changing expiry date of job (renew).
$( "div#renew_job_dialog_box" ).dialog({
    modal: true,
    autoOpen: false,
    draggable:false,
    width: 261,
    height:300,
    show: {
        effect: "fade"
    },
    close:function() {
        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        //Setting drop down previous value.
        $( $(this).data('renew_select_box') ).val( $.data( $(this).data('renew_select_box'), 'current' ) );
    },
    hide: {
        effect: "fade"
    },
    buttons: {
        OK: function() {
            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            renewJobExpiryDate( $( $(this).data('renew_select_box') ).attr("id"),$('input#job_expiry_date').val(),  $( $(this).data('renew_select_box') ));
        },
        Cancel: function() {
            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            //Setting drop down previous value.
            $( $(this).data('renew_select_box') ).val( $.data( $(this).data('renew_select_box'), 'current' ) );
        }
    }
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="renew_job_dialog_box" title="Renew Job" style = "display:none;height:300px">
    <p>
        <input id="job_expiry_date" class="job_expiry_date" type="text" readonly="" style="width:79%; margin-left:11px;" name="job_expiry_date">
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: I made [this fiddle but lack some more code](http://jsfiddle.net/3Q3zc/) complete the fiddle and include the link in your question..